# Discord Bot Responses twice

Tags: discord, discord.js

Hello so I am having an issue with my bot, it is sending responses twice. I am using Discord.js and I was trying to find solution from there for this too but was unable so that is why I came here to ask some smarter people.

```
bot.on('message', message => {


  // Muuttujalistaa:
  let msg = message.content.toUpperCase(); // Casesensitive VEKS!
  let sender = message.author; // Komennon käyttäjä
  let cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" "); // Leikkaa prefix pois komennosta
  let args = cont.slice(1); // Leikkaa pois commennon, jättäen argumentit



  if (msg === prefix + 'PING') { //Komento

    message.channel.send('PimpeliPOM!'); //vastaus komentoon
  }

  if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'MASSAPOISTO')) {

    async function purge() {
      message.delete(); // Poistaa komennon

      if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) { // Jos käyttäjällä on MANAGE_MESSAGES permission.
        message.channel.send(':x: :dizzy: **Sinulla ei riitä taikavoimat tähän.**')
        return;
      }

      if (isNaN(args[0])) {
        message.channel.send('Numeroita kaipailen, paljonko poistetaan? \n Käyttö: ' + prefix + 'massapoisto <määrä>');
        return;
      }

      const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: args[0]});
      console.log(fetched.size + ' viestiä löydetty, poistetaan...');


      // Viestien poisto
      message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched)
          .catch(error => message.channel.send(`Error: ${error}`));
      message.reply(' **Tsimsalapim, työni tehty on!** :dizzy:');

    }

    purge();

  }});
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIFZE.png) is the screenshot of the bot's respond

Comment: Try stopping the bot and running a command in Discord, if it can still respond then it means another instance of your bot is running in the background.

Comment: @Bauke Thank you that was it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the bot with two different instances. Shutting down one of them helped the bot to work normal again.